# jQuery - have different events if element is on the same row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a page with a row of boxes that are responsive........

so the smaller you resize the window the amount of boxes on each row lessens

heres a fiddle to show you whats going on

http://jsfiddle.net/abtPH/6/

Right now the behavior is......if you click on a box then a div appears under it.....if you click on the next box the div slides up a bit then slides down revealing the new content...

I want it so that if the box is on the same row and the user clicks the next one it does not slide up then down but fades the content in

I only want it to slide up when the box is on a different row...like underneath

heres my jquery so far

```
   $('li').on('click', function(e){
     $(this).siblings('.active').toggleClass('active', 400).find('.outer').slideToggle();
     $(this).find('.outer').slideToggle();
     $(this).toggleClass('active', 400);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is detecting what is on the same line.  For that I think the `position()` function is what you need.  When a list item is clicked, check to see if there is an active one already, if so, check to see if the current and active items have the same top value.  If they do crossfade otherwise toggle.

```
$('li').on('click', function(e){
  var active = $(this).siblings('.active');
  var posTop = ($(this).position()).top;
  if (active.length > 0) {
    var activeTop = (active.position()).top;
    if (activeTop == posTop) {
      active.toggleClass('active', 400).find('.outer').fadeOut('slow');
      $(this).find('.outer').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
      $(this).siblings('.active').toggleClass('active', 400).find('.outer').slideToggle();
      $(this).find('.outer').slideToggle();
    }
  } else {
    $(this).find('.outer').slideToggle();
  }
  $(this).toggleClass('active', 400);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abtPH/7/)

Comment: thats great!  WHat is .length on activeTop measuring extactly?

Comment: when a list item is clicked and there is no sibling with the .active class, `$(this).siblings('.active')` will return something like `Object[]`, so `active.length > 0` is only true if there was already an active sibling.